# What is the anteroom in a public toilet called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am looking for the name for that part of a public toilet where the mirrors are and you can powder your nose.

Comment: Aren't all convenience stores public? :) If you’re asking about a toilet, you should say that.

Comment: The [ADAAG](https://www.buildings.com/article-details/articleid/9242/title/the-ada-compliant-restroom) just calls them "sink areas".

Comment: Yes, a rest room / toilet,  but I want the name for the part where the mirrors are. I've amended my question to remove confusion about the word convenience.

Comment: @PhilSweet That could work, unless someone has another word/phrase?

Comment: There may be some more specific terms for the area in a ladies' restroom.  Is gender known?

Comment: If "public convenience/toilet“ isn't a well-recognised term where you were raised, please say so.

How could anyone equate “convenience stores” with “public toilets”?

Depending on locality, a public toilet” is, yes, a rest-room (facility)

I suggest, “public” makes no difference then, there’s no word or phrase for the wider part of the facility, where the mirrors are and you can powder your nose, nor is that an ante-room. Thee other part, where you do your private business, is broadly “the cubicles” but in 60 years of listening I’ve never once heard the wider area described separately.

Comment: Well,  I'm trying to relate that something happened to a lady in the area I'm asking about while her friend was in the cubicle doing business. So in relation to each other, I need to situate each of them.

Comment: @HotLicks: Ladies

Comment: @jsw29 I’d interpret an anteroom as a room you had to pass through to get to the one with the sinks and cubicles in. I think the OP means the part of the facilities room which is not occupied by cubicles.

Comment: Rest rooms usually do not have ante rooms. There are toilet stalls or urinals and in front of them are the mirrors and wash basins. Also, are you talking about a single toilet or a bunch of toilets (row of stalls).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My girlfriend always calls it **"Vanity Area"** of a public toilet, i.e. where you find vanities/sinks/mirrors. I don't know if it's the proper term. But it works for me. If you google "bathroom/toilet vanities", you will see lots of photos of the area you're talking about.

Answer (score 4):

Just would like to make a quick new contribution. While I like the term **vanity area**, I may offer a slightly unconventional term, as suggested by a British friend of mine: **Sinks'n'mirrors**. There was a girl at the **"sinks'n'mirrors**.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, it can be called a "womens lounge" if it's actually an anteroom with chairs and mirrors and perhaps a sink, but separate from the rest of the bathroom. It's where the co-toileters (?) wait.

> When I have seen a women's lounge, it is usually a larger room outside a toilet/restroom with vanities and some seating for fixing makeup, waiting for the restroom to be available, etc. From the hallway you go into the lounge, then from the lounge into the restroom. Also, sometimes men are not strictly forbidden from entering the lounge as they are from the restroom.

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/girls-lounge.2134285/

Comment: Another google golf hole in one. Co-toileter yields exactly one prior use.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean but that's too fancy for what I'm thinking of.

Comment: women's lounges don't have wash basins. Only mirrors with chairs in front of them. Some will even have a couch. You see this at companies, so if you well unwell you can take a short rest.

Answer (score 2):

In a public bathroom, you have stalls, urinals (if it's a men's bathroom), and sinks. Some "family" bathrooms will have a baby-changing area (just a pull-down table against one wall).

You say are you are looking for:

> that part of a public toilet where the mirrors are and you can powder your nose.

If you are standing at that location, you are "standing in front of the sink."

Short of uncommon and fancy bathrooms, that might have a separate dressing room or vanity area, that's all public bathrooms are: a single room, with a few amenities in different locations.

If you're waiting in line for a bathroom, you are waiting outside the bathroom.

In a comment, you say:

> Well, I'm trying to relate that something happened to a lady in the area I'm asking about while her friend was in the cubicle doing business. So in relation to each other, I need to situate each of them.

To describe this, you could say:

> Both she and her friend were in the bathroom. Her friend was in a stall, and she was standing in front of the sink.

Comment: I have a sink in my kitchen but in public rest rooms or even a bathroom in a house, those are basins, not sinks.

Comment: @Lambie To the extent that the terms are consistently differentiated at all (which, mostly, they aren’t nowadays, except to the extent that _basin_ is much less common), their main distinction is that a sink is an integrated system consisting of a basin (the hollowed-out bowl itself) fitted with taps and plugs, and fixed to a drain. As such, both kitchens and restrooms do have sinks. The relative prevalence of _basin_ referring to the restroom ones is merely a result of kitchen sinks having a longer history of being fixed with drains; in restrooms, they remained unconnected much longer.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Public restrooms are not said to have sinks. Technically, a sink and a hand basin are the same thing. However, generally, sinks are for kitchens/basements and (wash or hand) basins are for bathrooms/restrooms. That's the usage.

Comment: @Lambie There is no such thing as “the” usage. That is _your_ usage. It is very, very far from being universal. The majority of English speakers do not make this distinction; most generally call both sinks. This was originally mainly AmE, but nowadays most Brits have followed suit. Nobody calls the one in the kitchen a basin unless talking specifically about the bowl, but people consistently calling the restroom ones only basins are a definite minority now.

Comment: @Lambie I've never heard of the word **basin** used in the context of a public bathroom in North America. Sometimes it's used to describe something in a laundry room (a laundry basin or wash basin) but those are still more commonly referred to as laundry sinks. The use of **basin** sounds more European to me. (If I look at Google Books Ngram, the American corpus uses **sink** more often than **basin**, and the reverse is true of the British corpus.)

Comment: http://shop.iccsafe.org/media/wysiwyg/material/7053S11-sample.pdf They may use sink, I prefer basin.

Comment: The OP asked for 'the name' for this space. If I understand this answer correctly, it implies that there is **no name**  for it. If so, it may help the clarity to say so explicitly.